# Elixir list comprehension

Tags: elixir

I have a list of tuples :

```
m=[{5, 3}, {6, 6}, {7, 10}]
```

Now I want to create a second list such that for each tuple of values inside m I will insert "A" if first value>second value and "B" if first < second. So in this case the list will result in ["A","B"] ( since 5>3 and 7<10)
I used the following code :

```
res= for {u,v} <- m do if u>v do "A" end
                       if u<v do "B" end 
                    end
```

However it is resulting in the following :

```
[nil, nil, "B"]
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not able to figure out what is wrong?

Your first `if` expression is being ignored completely by the compiler because you have another expression after that (you should get a warning if you compile this in a Mix project). Elixir only returns the value of the last expression, which in this case is either `"B"` (when `u < v`) or `nil` otherwise.

You can either use `else` with `if` or `cond` here so that there's only one expression in the `do`:

```
res = for {u,v} <- m do
  if u > v do
    "A"
  else
    "B"
  end
end
```

or

```
res = for {u,v} <- m do
  cond do
     u > v -> "A"
     u < v -> "B"
  end
end
```

Note that the first one will return `"B"` if `u == v` and the second one will raise an exception if `u == v`. I'm not sure which one you want.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want to ignore u==v. I had already tried the first solution but it was including the equality case which I just want to ignore.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem that I had. I only wanted to calculate the number of As and Bs in the second list so in the cond do I just added a different condition for u==v. Thanks a lot.

Comment: for-comprehensions can filter as well, so if you simply want to ignore `u == v`, you could add the filter `u != v`. Thus, `for {u, v} <- m, u != v, do: if(u > v do: "A", else: "B")`

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of couple of commas:

```
iex(252)> res= for {u,v} <- m, do: if u>v, do: "A", else: "B"
["A", "B", "B"]
```